i am making a face authentication program using opencv and deepface model in python
I wrote this function but is some times give me this error
"Authenticated as Muhammad Zair
[ WARN:0@19.686] global cap_msmf.cpp:1768 CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147483638
Deleting the database object"

here is the function:
@staticmethod
    def authenticate_user(users):
        video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        start_time = time.time()
        capture = False
        frame = None
        flag = False

        def video_thread():
            nonlocal capture, frame
            while not flag:
                capture, frame = video.read()
                if not capture:
                    continue
        
        def video_show():
            while not flag:
                if frame is not None:
                    cv2.imshow("the video", frame)
                    cv2.waitKey(1) 
        
        capture_thread1 = threading.Thread(target=video_thread)
        capture_thread1.start()

        capture_thread2 = threading.Thread(target = video_show)
        capture_thread2.start()

        while time.time() - start_time < 20 and not flag:
            if capture:
                for user in users:
                    user_id, user_name, user_type, image_path = user
                    registered_image = cv2.imread(image_path)
                    result = DeepFace.verify(frame, registered_image, model_name='VGG-Face', enforce_detection=False)
                    if result['verified']:
                        print(f"Authenticated as {user_name}")
                        flag = True
                        break
        video.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        if flag:
            return user_type                
        print("Failed to authenticate ")
        sys.exit()

I was expecting that after the face authentication, the program will work normally and exit the function. but it is giving a error warning in the terminal, it does not terminate the program, but I want to resolve it.

You are reading the video from the capture_thread1, so you need to release it in the thread. Otherwise, the thread will try to read the video that has already been released.
Also, you need to destroy the windows in the capture_thread2.
It would also be helpful to have a stop command that you can trigger when using a thread. I made it with your flag, you can see an example below:
import cv2
import time
import threading
import sys
from deepface import DeepFace

def authenticate_user():
        video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        start_time = time.time()
        capture = False
        frame = None
        flag = False

        def video_thread(arg):
            nonlocal capture, frame
            capture_thread1 = threading.currentThread()
            while getattr(capture_thread1, "flag", True):
                capture, frame = video.read(2)
                if not capture:
                    continue
            video.release()
        
        def video_show(arg):
            capture_thread2 = threading.currentThread()
            while getattr(capture_thread2, "flag", True):
                if frame is not None:
                    cv2.imshow("the video", frame)
                    cv2.waitKey(1) 
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        
        capture_thread1 = threading.Thread(target=video_thread, args=("task",))
        capture_thread1.start()

        capture_thread2 = threading.Thread(target = video_show, args=("task",))
        capture_thread2.start()

        while time.time() - start_time < 20 and not flag:
            if capture:
                registered_image = cv2.imread("./my_img.jpg")#try with your path!!!
                result = DeepFace.verify(frame, registered_image, model_name='VGG-Face', enforce_detection=False)
                if result['verified']:
                    print(f"Authenticated as you")
                    capture_thread1.flag = False
                    capture_thread2.flag = False
                    break
        

        if capture_thread1.flag == False:
            return 1                
        print("Failed to authenticate ")
        sys.exit()

authenticate_user()


well i have solved it by adding some sleep time time.sleep(0.1) , however , thank you for helping :)
